# nested unique_ptr and stl containers

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have recently read about RAII and have begun using it. I am trying to define graph as adjacency list and allocate the entire DS on heap using `unique_ptr`. I know that I can define them as stack objects, but I am trying to use `unique_ptr`'s to get used to them.

I am doing the following

```
unique_ptr to vector  --
                       |-->(unique_ptr)list<edge>
                       |-->(unique_ptr)list<edge>
                       |-->(unique_ptr)list<edge>
                       |-->(unique_ptr)list<edge>
```

Code:

```
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

struct edge {
    int vertex;
    int weight;
};
int vertices = 10;
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<list<struct edge > > > >
    adj_list(new vector<list<struct edge> >(10)); // THIS COMPILES

unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<list<struct edge > > > >
    adj_list(new vector<list<struct edge> >(10, new list<edge>())); //THIS GIVES COMPILATION ERROR
```

Can anyone help me correct this?

EDIT:

I have doubt regarding vector being RAII classes.
if I do the following

```
vector<int> *v;
v = new vector<int> (10);
```

Do I have to delete the variable `v`. Or will it automatically free the memory on heap, when it goes out of scope ?

EDIT:
using pointer to vector makes the user responsible for memory management.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: RAII doesn't necessarily mean smart pointers. `vector` and `list` are perfectly good RAII classes themselves; managing them with `unique_ptr` doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `unique_ptr`s are unnecessary. Just use the objects themselves:

```
vector<list<edge>> adj_list;
```

RAII does not imply smart pointers, it's the other way around. C++ accomodated RAII long before smart pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `vector`'s constructors [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). None of them accepts a pointer to the element. So either use `vector<list<struct edge>*>` or change the call to this:

```
list<struct edge> emptyList;
... (new vector<list<struct edge> >(10, emptyList));
```